# How do I display a column in table a based on the average of a column in table b?

Tags: sql, database

I'm doing an sql project for school and one of the requirements is "List all interns with average hire index of 3.5 or higher." How do I do this?

```
CREATE TABLE Intern (
internID INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Person(personID)
,School VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
,Major VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
,ExpGradDate VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE Evaluation (
HireIndex INT(1) DEFAULT NULL
,EvalID INT DEFAULT NULL
,FOREIGN KEY (EvalID) REFERENCES Intern(internID)
);
```

Below is what I tried, but it's not working. I'm getting error code 1111: invalid use of group function.

```
SELECT internID
FROM intern 
INNER JOIN evaluation ON intern.internID = evaluation.EvalID
WHERE AVG(evaluation.HireIndex >= 3.5);
```

I have the insert statements all done and working for every column, and HireIndex contains ints ranged from 1 to 5.

Comment: You missed basic knowledge about SQL

Comment: This is my first time working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause, and the restriction in the `WHERE` clause, which is intended for groups, should be moved to a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
    i.internID
FROM intern i
INNER JOIN evaluation e
    ON i.internID = e.EvalID
GROUP BY
    i.internID
HAVING
    AVG(e.HireIndex >= 3.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT i.internID,avg(e.HireIndex)
FROM intern i
INNER JOIN evaluation e ON i.internID = e.EvalID
group by i.InterId
having avg(e.HireIndex)>=3.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

No `JOIN` is required for this query if you only want the intern id:

```
SELECT e.EvalID
FROM ievaluation e
GROUP BY e.EvalID
HAVING AVG(e.HireIndex) >= 3.5;
```

You don't specify your database, although the code looks like MySQL.  The above works in MySQL because MySQL will convert the integer to a numeric for the average.  Some databases only do integer averages (so the average of 2 and 3 and 2, not 2.5.  So, I often write such logic as:

```
HAVING AVG(e.HireIndex * 1.0) >= 3.5;
```

just to be sure.